# Bulk Copy Program (bcp) Utility - Error Importing CSV - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: azure, csv, import, azure-active-directory, bcp

I have not yet been successful at bulk importing CSV files into Azure SQL Server using the BCP Utility.  I continue to receive the error `The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted`.

Here is my Script/Code:

```
bcp DestinationDatabase.Table IN `
"C:\Data\CSVDataNeedingImported.csv" `
-c -G `
-U myAzureUserName@domain.com `
-P $pass `
-S AzureServerName
```

I have little experience setting up certificates.  I am needing to know where or what I should do next.  I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

**Full Error**:

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -2146893019
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted
.


SQLState = 08001, NativeError = -2146893019
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
```

Screenshot of PowerShell ISE:

[image: PowerShell ISE BCP Certificate Chain Error]

Comment: The issue and answer really is my company had not yet moved our SQL Server DBs to Azure Managed Instances and so the -G option was not required as we are using Windows Authentication and so the -T switch was needing to be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the following

```
bcp DimDate2 in C:\Users\....\mycsvfile.csv -S knewserver -d  Mysqldb -U Kavya -P sjjhs@123 
Error:
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. 
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 53
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or n
ot accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

[image]

Destination table must contain similar table columns as the copying data

```
CREATE TABLE destb
    (
        name char NOT NULL,
        rno TINYINT NOT NULL,
        
    )
    ;
```

Make sure the server has network access enabled

[image]

I could get past the error by using -T which

Following command worked for me

**`bcp destb in C:\Users\...\mycsvfile.txt -S knewserver.database.windows.net -d  Mysqldb -U Kavya -P Sgfhgr@123 -q -c -t ","`**

[image]

Refer [Load data from CSV file into a database (bcp) - Azure SQL | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/load-from-csv-with-bcp?view=azuresql)

Comment: Than you.  I ended up needing the -T to utilize Windows Auth.  The SQL Database has not yet moved to an Azure Managed Instance and so it turns out I was not needing the -G -U or -P switches.